# assign a reference to an indicator dnamically in a for loop

Tags: loops, path, reference, labview, indicator

I have a large number of internal path references in a LabVIEW project. Each path is entered manually into a bundle function along with a reference to a numeric indicator on the block diagram. Because I have a lot of paths and therefore a lot of numeric indicators, the block diagram is a big mess.

I want to streamline this by having a CSV file with a nx2 array. on column 1 I want to have the path of the internal reference itself. On column 2 I want to have the name of the numeric indicator (already placed in the block diagram and front panel) that corresponds to the path in column 1. Using a for loop I want to loop over each row of the CSV file and using a bundle function, bundle the path (on index 0) and a reference to the numeric indicator itself. Here is the actual problem I am having since I don't know how to dynamically assign the name of the numeric indicator (on index 1) to a digital reference as the loop executes. See the state of my current VI for more reference. Please help me find a way to dynamically crate digital reference to each numeric indicator as the loop goes through.

Right now, the closest I got to the goal is to get the name of the numeric indicator (index 1 on the CSV) assigned to a string reference, but my numeric indicators are still unreferenced and not connected to the bundle function.

Note that the column 2 in the CSV has the same name as the numeric indicators, so "numeric","numeric 1", "numeric 2", "numeric 3", "numeric 4[image]"

Answer (score 1):

Read this https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/How-to-get-control-reference-from-control-indicator-label-name/td-p/3884075 to learn how to obtain control/indicator reference by its name. That should solve your problem. Use first CSV column as file path and the second column to obtain indicator reference. Then bundle two of them and that's it!